# Script not run with cron

Tags: cron, path

i have a python script when i launch my script all it's ok but when i lauchn my scrypt under crontab

[image: 4]
[image: 5]

***i have this errors:***

> .. 2015-04-24 14:36:02,163 ERROR  Problème dans le module
>   importData[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/opt/scripts/stockvo.json' ..

[image: 0]
[image: 1]
[image: 2]

***My script py:***

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

def moveFTPFiles(serverName,userName,passWord,remotePath,localPath,deleteRemoteFiles=False,onlyDiff=False):
    """Connect to an FTP server and bring down files to a local directory"""
    import os
    import sys
    import glob
    from sets import Set
    import ftplib 

    logger.info(' Suppressions des anciennes photos du repertoire: '+localDirectoryPath)

    os.chdir(localDirectoryPath)
    files=glob.glob('*.*')
    for filename in files:
        os.unlink(filename)


    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(serverName)
        ftp.login(userName,passWord)
        ftp.cwd(remotePath)
        logger.info(' Connexion au serveur '+serverName)
        logger.info(' Téléchargement des photos depuis '+serverName+' vers le repertoire '+localDirectoryPath)
        if onlyDiff:
            lFileSet = Set(os.listdir(localPath))
            rFileSet = Set(ftp.nlst())
            transferList = list(rFileSet - lFileSet)
            logger.info(' Nombres de photos à récuperer ' + str(len(transferList)))
        else:
            transferList = ftp.nlst()
        delMsg = "" 
        filesMoved = 0
        for fl in transferList:
            # create a full local filepath
            localFile = localPath + fl
            # print "Create a full local filepath: " + localFile
            grabFile = True
            if grabFile:                
                #open a the local file
                fileObj = open(localFile, 'wb')
                # Download the file a chunk at a time using RETR
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + fl, fileObj.write)
                # Close the file
                # print "Close the file "
                fileObj.close()
                filesMoved += 1
                #print "Uploaded: " + str(filesMoved)
                #sys.stdout.write(str(filesMoved)+' ')
                #sys.stdout.flush()

            # Delete the remote file if requested
            if deleteRemoteFiles:
                ftp.delete(fl)
                delMsg = " and Deleted"         

        logger.info(' Nombre de photos récupérées' + delMsg + ': ' + str(filesMoved) + ' le ' + timeStamp())
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        logger.error(' Problème dans le module moveFTPFiles' + '%s' % e)
    ftp.close() # Close FTP connection
    ftp = None

def timeStamp():
    """returns a formatted current time/date"""
    import time
    return str(time.strftime("%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p"))

def importData(serverName,userName,passWord,directory,filematch,source,destination):
    import socket
    import ftplib
    import os
    import subprocess
    import json

    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(serverName)
        ftp.login(userName,passWord)
        ftp.cwd(directory)
        logger.info(' Connexion au serveur '+serverName)
        # Loop through matching files and download each one individually
        for filename in ftp.nlst(filematch):
            local_filename = os.path.join('/opt/scripts/', filename)
            fhandle = open(local_filename, 'wb')
            logger.info(' Téléchargement du fichier de données ' + filename)
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)
            fhandle.close()

        #convert xml to json
        logger.info(' Conversion du fichier ' + filename + ' au format .json ')
        subprocess.call('xml2json -t xml2json -o /opt/scripts/stockvo.json /opt/scripts/stockvo.xml --strip_text', shell=True)

        #modify json file
        logger.info(' Modification du fichier .json')
        data = json.loads(open("/opt/scripts/stockvo.json").read())
        with open("/opt/scripts/stockvo.json", "w") as outfile:
                json.dump(data["Stock"]["Vehicule"], outfile)

        #move json file
        logger.info(' Déplacement du fichier de données .json vers le répertoire /opt/scripts/')
        os.system('mv %s %s' % ('/opt/scripts/stockvo.json', '/opt/data/stockvo.json'))

        #import json file to MongoDB
        logger.info(' Import du fichier .json vers la base MongoDB')
        #subprocess.call('mongoimport --db AutoPrivilege -c cars stockvo.json --jsonArray --upsert --drop',shell=True)
        p = subprocess.Popen(['mongoimport', '--db', 'AutoPrivilege', '-c', 'cars', '/opt/data/stockvo.json', '--jsonArray', '--upsert', '--drop'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        stdout, stderr = p.communicate()

        if stdout:
            logger.info(stdout)

        if stderr:
            logger.error(stderr)


        #remove xml file
        logger.info(' Suppression du fichier ' + filename)
        ## if file exists, delete it ##
        myfile="/opt/scripts/stockvo.xml"
        if os.path.isfile(myfile):
            os.remove(myfile)

    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        logger.error(' Problème dans le module importData' + '%s' % e)
    ftp.close() # Close FTP connection
    ftp = None

import time
import datetime
import re
import os
import stat
import logging
import logging.handlers as handlers
import subprocess

class SizedTimedRotatingFileHandler(handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler):
    """
    Handler for logging to a set of files, which switches from one file
    to the next when the current file reaches a certain size, or at certain
    timed intervals
    """
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='a', maxBytes=0, backupCount=0, encoding=None,
                 delay=0, when='h', interval=1, utc=False):
        # If rotation/rollover is wanted, it doesn't make sense to use another
        # mode. If for example 'w' were specified, then if there were multiple
        # runs of the calling application, the logs from previous runs would be
        # lost if the 'w' is respected, because the log file would be truncated
        # on each run.
        if maxBytes > 0:
            mode = 'a'
        handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler.__init__(
            self, filename, when, interval, backupCount, encoding, delay, utc)
        self.maxBytes = maxBytes

    def shouldRollover(self, record):
        """
        Determine if rollover should occur.

        Basically, see if the supplied record would cause the file to exceed
        the size limit we have.
        """
        if self.stream is None:                 # delay was set...
            self.stream = self._open()
        if self.maxBytes > 0:                   # are we rolling over?
            msg = "%s\n" % self.format(record)
            self.stream.seek(0, 2)  #due to non-posix-compliant Windows feature
            if self.stream.tell() + len(msg) >= self.maxBytes:
                return 1
        t = int(time.time())
        if t >= self.rolloverAt:
            return 1
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':      

    #log to a file
    log_filename='/opt/log/importData.log'
    logger=logging.getLogger()  
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler=SizedTimedRotatingFileHandler(
        log_filename, maxBytes=10000, backupCount=5,
        when='s',interval=60,
        # encoding='bz2',  # uncomment for bz2 compression
    )
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    #--- constant connection values
    ftpServerName = "xxx.xx
    ftpU = "xxxx"
    ftpP = "xxxx"
    remoteDirectoryPath = "/xx/xxx/xxx/"
    localDirectoryPath = "/xx/xx/xx/xxxx/"

    directory = '/datas/'
    filematch = '*.xml'
    source='/opt/scripts/'
    destination='/opt/data/'
    start = time.time()
    logger.info('================================================')
    logger.info('================  DEBUT SCRIPT =================')
    logger.info('================================================')
    deleteAfterCopy = False     #set to true if you want to clean out the remote directory
    onlyNewFiles = True         #set to true to grab & overwrite all files locally
    importData(ftpServerName,ftpU,ftpP,directory,filematch,source,destination)
#   moveFTPFiles(ftpServerName,ftpU,ftpP,remoteDirectoryPath,localDirectoryPath,deleteAfterCopy,onlyNewFiles)
    end = time.time()
    elapsed_time = end - start
    now = time.strftime("%H:%M", time.localtime(elapsed_time))
    logger.info('================================================')
    logger.info('================== FIN SCRIPT ==================')
    logger.info('======== Tps d''execution: ' + now + ' minutes =========')
    logger.info('================================================')
```

***Update:***

add my fodler in my `$PATH`:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/scripts`

is what I forgot some things (privilege,..)?

Comment: Could be. When you call `subprocess.call(...)`, you're ignoring the return code. Perhaps one of those calls failed? By checking the return values of those calls, you could find out if one of them failed. (In particular, maybe the `xml2json` call failed?) A good way to check the return code might be to use `subprocess.check_call()` instead of `subprocess.call()`.

Comment: @DanGetz it's possible my user `autoprivilege` is not allowed to execute the command `xml2json ....` ..?

Comment: @Mercer, The problem is the `PATH` variable which needs to be defined within cron explicitly. `/opt/scripts` is not in your path e.g  `echo "$PATH"` won't show it. You can add e.g  `PATH=/opt/scripts:/usr/bin:/etc/etc/etc....` on top of the crontab and solve the problem.  As a side note:  `*/1 * * * *` is equal to `* * * * *`

Comment: @val0x00ff actually i have this on my `$PATH`  --> `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games`

Comment: @Mercer Alright, so now try  to add to crontab the line:  `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/scripts`

Comment: @val0x00ff i have modified my $Path but i have the same error

Comment: @Mercer  can you update your question and add the changes you made?

Comment: @Christopher update the cron but same pb

Comment: @Mercer Please show your crontab content. Also the error you're getting now.

Comment: @val0x00ff `*/1 * * * * bash -lc /opt/scripts/importData.py
`

Comment: @Mercer  are you even reading my comments?  You don't need the `*/1* ..`  Also remove `bash ..`  You are not running a bash script.  On top of your crontab  put `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/scripts`  then the second line  `* * * * * /opt/scripts/importData.py`

Comment: @val0x00ff ok it's work thx, but how can i do for lauchn my script every day at 4:00 am .?

Comment: @Mercer that is `0 4 * * * /opt/scripts/importData.py`

Comment: @val0x00ff ok thx post you're answer if you want me validates your answer

Comment: @Mercer answer your own question and let others know how it is solved. Spare me the effort!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To resolve my problem I added these lines to crontab

```
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/scripts 
0 4 * * * /opt/scripts/importData.py
```

thank you to val0x00ff who gave me the solution